# Force open a shared SharePoint list link in a browser on a mobile device

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list that I would like to share with external users, some might not have a Microsoft 365 account. I have created the link so anyone have access to the list. The link works great in a browser on a laptop when I open in a private browser.

I then generate a QR code for this link. When I scan the QR code on an iOS mobile device it force open in the Microsoft Lists app. It then says "Permission Required - You don't have permission to view this list".

I then tried to open the link in a browser on an iOS mobile device and that worked fine.

So the question is. How do I force the link to open in a browser instead of the Microsoft Lists app?

I have tried to append "web=1" to the link but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Could you please confirm the system of your device? Android or IOS?

Comment: It's on an iOS mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using an iPhone, there are a few different ways to open links in your browser of choice instead of in the default app. One way is to long press on the link (this works in most apps), which will bring up a menu with the option to “Open in Safari.” You can also change your default browser settings so that all links automatically open in Safari or another browser.

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.